# Include creating HTTP 500

Tags: php

So, I am just about ready to kill a kitten. This is driving me up the wall.

I have a php file I need to include, call it `functions.php`  I have tried the following to include it:-

- `include './includes/functions.php';`

When I did this, I discovered that I get a White Screen of Death. So I went onto more creative solutions;

- `echo ((include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/includes/functions.php") == 'OK') ? 'GOOD IMPORT' : 'BAD IMPORT';`

This was purely to see a visual response to the import. But to no avail, still the White Screen of Emptiness.

The file does exist.

Please, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 500 is an internal server error. Check your error log.

Comment: there is an error in your included file `functions.php` try opening that file and see what error you get, you may be missing a `;` or a `{` some where.

Comment: Ok, what am I looking for in the logs?

Comment: Run your `include.php` file through this.. http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/ and you will see any syntax errors.

Comment: @cmorrissey, NetBeans is not picking up any errors... I also have error reporting on.. `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`, `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`,`error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @ThomasEllis, 'No syntax errors in CODE'

Comment: Can you share your directory structure of where the files are?  If you're traversing the directory incorrectly, then include will be looking in the wrong location.

Comment: ini_set doesn't catch parse errors, or fatal errors that occur before them. Your best bet is to edit the php.ini

Comment: As an experiment, try copy-pasting the code into your source file (instead of including it). That will tell you whether the problem is with the include statement or with the included code itself. Also check whether there is a problem with including the file _twice_ (use include_once instead).

Comment: @PhilPerry, thanks solved it.. Problem was that in the included code, I was require(ing) something that couldn't have the stream opened due to not finding the file. It is all sorted now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `/includes/functions.php` has a syntax error, To stop the "White screen of Death" edit your php.ini

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

are values you should probably use. Thats from a stock php.ini file

Comment: I already have error reporting on.. `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`, `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`,`error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Its not triggering. Otherwise it wouldnt show that page, Do it before the script level to show all errors, The script needs to be parsed for  your way to work